# Is it possible to call Dart code generated with dartdevc from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-dev-compiler

I have a bunch of Dart libraries that a customer wants to call from JavaScript. Is it possible to call functions created with dartdevc from JS?

Comment: Sure, but DDC output is not intended to be used in production, it's only for development and for production still dart2js should be used.
I have heard, that some actually use DDC for production, but it's not officially supported. `dart2js` output can't be called from JS except specific predefined entry-points.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245957/compiling-dart-into-minifier-friendly-javascript-from-dartdevc-into-google-clos/45247781#45247781

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to call functions, you can probably do that in this way. Although I only know it's works for functions, probably not for whole class. I am also not sure about dartdevc support, but dart2js should be able to do this:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

main() {
  js.context['methodFromDart'] = doMyStuff;
}

void doMyStuff(String text) => print(text);
```

And then in you Javascript you are free to do:

```
methodFromDart("Hello world to Dart!");
```